# vb.net Handling the server response when trying to read xml from some page

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function which i use to get html source from my website

```
Public Function GetPageHTML(ByVal URL As String, _
      Optional ByVal TimeoutSeconds As Integer = 10) _
      As String
        ' Retrieves the HTML from the specified URL,
        ' using a default timeout of 10 seconds
        Dim objRequest As Net.WebRequest
        Dim objResponse As Net.WebResponse
        Dim objStreamReceive As System.IO.Stream
        Dim objEncoding As System.Text.Encoding
        Dim objStreamRead As System.IO.StreamReader

        Try
            ' Setup our Web request
            objRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
            objRequest.Timeout = TimeoutSeconds * 1000
            ' Retrieve data from request

            Try
                objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse 'some times it gives an error server unavailable 503
            Catch ex As WebException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try

            objStreamReceive = objResponse.GetResponseStream
            objEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding( _
                "utf-8")

            objStreamRead = New System.IO.StreamReader( _
                objStreamReceive, objEncoding)
            ' Set function return value

            GetPageHTML = objStreamRead.ReadToEnd()
            ' Check if available, then close response
            If Not objResponse Is Nothing Then
                objResponse.Close()
            End If
        Catch
            ' Error occured grabbing data, simply return nothing
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function
```

some times the objResponse gives error "503 Server unavailable" and many other errors like 403 and so on, how can i handle each of those errors independently?

how can i make this function retry the request after sometime? problem is the try statement doesn't seem to handle this and i am not sure why i don't see the exception MsgBox but it shows the error on the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the response as a HttpWebResponse object and do a Select Case of it's StatusCode Property.  You'll have to clean and finish this up, but here is an example:

```
    Select Case CType(objResponse, Net.HttpWebResponse).StatusCode

        Case Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
            'This is sloppy, but a quick example for one of your sub-questions.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            'Try again.
            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse
        Case Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            'Error Handling
        Case Net.HttpStatusCode.OK
            'Proceed as normal.
        Case Else
            'Error Handling

    End Select
```