# How can you ignore server errors in vb.net? In C# you just a try/catch and ignore then exception

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

I've writing a program for Instagram and when I upload the images from a user sometimes I get a 503 error (server unavailable). That can be expected but how do I ignore the error completely with no pop up message. I'm in debug mode and I wonder if it'll do the same in release mode. I have most of my code in try/catch and I don't respond to the exception. It works well in C#.

Comment: Better question - why are you getting random 503 errors? That should probably be solved first.

Comment: Errors are not meant to be ignored...Instead of trying to find out how to ignore them, maybee you should focus on how to solve them

Comment: Well basically I scraped all of the links from a site and then I use a background worker to add them to a listview. Out of around 1300 pictures I get at least two server errors. I don't mind knowing there's a server problem I just don't want other users to have click on some error message. Also, the images get add to the listview really fast. Maybe that causes a problem. Should I slow it down a bit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6124158/3436942. Or, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12289757/3436942

Answer (score 2):

This is for specific problem: 
The compiler breaks in Debug mode even when in Try..Catch block.

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+E`. It will open the Exceptions dialog box as shown in the screenshot below.
   [image]
2. Uncheck everything in the `Thrown` column and click OK.

This should resolve the problem.

**EDIT :**

Those are the default settings anyways. So you can also click the `Reset All` button, and it should automatically uncheck all the `Thrown` checkboxes.